# Continuous function on a sequentially compact space

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove that a continuous function on sequentially compact space attain a maximum and a minimum. Could someone give me an idea how to handle it? Thanks. :)

Comment: There are some information is missing. Do you mean a function as $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The answer below proves the result for real valued functions. I suspect it doesn't hold for general functions into an ordered topological space, and the likely counterexample is the one point compactification of the minimal uncountable well ordered set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function with $X$ sequentially compact. First we show that $f(X)$ must have an upper bound. If not, we could construct a sequence of points $x_1,x_2,\ldots$ such that the set $\{f(x_i)\}$ has no upper bound in $\mathbb{R}$. The sequence has a convergent subsequence in $X$, but the image of the convergent subsequence has no upper bound and hence the function values on the subsequence do not converge, contradicting continuity of $f$. Thus, $f(X)$ has an upper bound.

If the upper bound of $f(X)$ is not a limit point of $f(X)$, then it must be equal to $f(x)$  for some $x\in X$, and hence the function attains a maximum. Otherwise we can construct a sequence of points $x_1',x_2',\ldots$ such that $f(x_i')$ converges to the maximum of $f(X)$. The sequence must have a convergent subsequence, and by continuity of $f$ the limit is the point $x'\in X$ such that $f(x')$ is the maximum of $f(X)$, so $f$ attains its maximum.

Comment: Yeah, dude. The function is real-valued. Also, thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @Bohrer you're welcome